# Why does whitespaces matter in this case for antlr4?

Tags: parsing, whitespace, antlr4

Lets say I have this grammar, written with Antlr4:

```
grammar Test;
start : expr* ;

expr : expr '-' expr
    | INT ;

MINUS : '-' ;
INT: MINUS? DIGIT+ ; // Disclaimer: this definition of an integer is just for illustration purposes

DIGIT : '0'..'9' ;

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines
```

My thought process is that `1-1` should be the same as `1 - 1`; which should be `expr '-' expr`. In case of `1 - 1`

```
      start
      expr(-)

expr(1)     expr(1)
```

Above tree seems correct, which again evaluated to `expr '-' expr`.

But when not using spaces, antlr think there are two INT expr. In case of `1-1`

```
       start
expr(1)     expr(-1)
```

Should not all whitespaces (with the `WS` rule) be skipped, which means both of the expression should be parsed the same way?

Answer (score 1):

Lexer rules match as  much characters as possible, so `- 1` is tokenised as a `MINUS` and an `INT` and `-1` (without the space) as s single `INT`.

You must realise that the lexer does not listen to the parser. If the parser tries to match the tokens `INT MINUS INT` for the input `1-1`, the lexer does not produce these tokens. Because the lexer matches as much characters as possible, it will always create two `INT` tokens for that input (no `MINUS`!). Parsing and tokenisation are 2 separate steps.

Comment: But should not the first rule be parsed, if it matches? Which is `expr '-' expr` in both cases?

Comment: @gel `expr '-' expr` doesn't match because there's no '-' token in the token stream, only an INT token. The key idea here is that the lexer turns the input into a stream of tokens without caring about the parser rules at all and then the parser only sees the tokens in that stream, so it doesn't see a `-` because the lexer already turned `-1` into a single INT token.

Comment: I think I almost get it. But spaces are skipped? So should not `1-1` and `1 - 1` be exactly the same?

Comment: @gel Whitespace isn't skipped within tokens. The lexer looks at the input and the list of lexer rules and then decides which of the rules to apply on the current input. If multiple rules match on the current input, the one that produces the longest match is chosen (and in case of ties, the one that comes first in the grammar). The `-> skip` in your `WS` rule means that, if the `WS` rule is applied, the lexer doesn't put a corresponding token into the token stream, but just continues with the next token. That doesn't mean that the previous token can extend over this skipped token.

Comment: @gel: In other words `- 1` matches the `'-'` rule, the `WS` rule and then the `INT` rule in that order. Because of the `-> skip` only the `'-'` token and the `INT` token make it into the stream. But that doesn't change the fact that `- 1` doesn't match the `INT` rule because the `INT` rule doesn't allow spaces. You shouldn't think of it as "spaces are ignored" so much as "whenever the WS rule matches, it doesn't generate a token" and since lexer rules aren't matched inside of other lexer rules, this won't affect whether a given lexer rule matches or not.